# CORS error , but springboot app has cross origins annotation

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, rest

My spring boot code is

```
  @GetMapping("/currentUser")
public Map<String, String> testController(Authentication authentication){
    User user=(User)authentication.getPrincipal();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Role",user.getUserRole().toString());
    map.put("Lname",user.getLastName());
    map.put("Fname", user.getFirstName());
    return map;
}
```

ReactJS code is

```
 useEffect(() => {
  

       
          axios.get('currentUser',{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} },{withCredentials: true},{ crossDomain: true })
          .then(response =>{
             console.log(response);})
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });},[]);
```

my login and signup (post requests) work but this returns the following error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/currentUser. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/currentUser. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I suggest you to check the following:

1. Do you have the following Annotation at your controller class? It is not shown in your example.

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
```

But keep in mind that "*" will allow all origin to access the page. If suggest to restrict this value for production.

2. Check your browser network tab in the development tools. This issue can be caused if the request results in a 404 (not found), too. Therefore the CORS message isn´t the cause of your problem.

Comment: thankyou for the answer. i checked the network the tab and the status is "blocked"

Comment: Ok. In most of the cases you get further information in the "console" tab of your browser development tools. All common browser tell the reason why a request has been blocked there.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the support for cross-origin by using the annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` by adding it to your controllers **or** if you want to add for specific controller method, you can achieve the same by adding the annotation to your method only. Another way to add the support for cross-origin globally by creating the bean as following

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

You can also mention particular origin instead of '*' like
for eg: `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")`